# Material Card View stroke color isn't appiled

Tags: android, material-design

I am using following code to apply stroke color in `MaterialCardView`.But the color isn't applied?

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
     app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" 
     app:strokeColor="@color/primaryOrange" 
     app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" 
     app:strokeWidth="1dp">
```

Comment: which version of material components are you using and what about the app theme?

Comment: I am using 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' and base theme is <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

Comment: You have to use a MaterialComponents theme

Comment: how to apply that. Do you have any idea without changing the base theme of app.

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme